# Count number of lines in a string in java - BufferedReader behavior

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-io

I am using the function **countLines** to count the number of lines in a string. It uses StringReader and BufferedReader. But I get a different result than I expected for the string **test** in my example. Can somebody verify this scenario and tell if BufferedReader behaves as expected.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class LineCountTest {

    private static final String test = "This is a\ntest string\n\n\n";
    private static final String test2 = "This is a\ntest string\n\n\n ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Line count: " + countLines(test));
        System.out.println("Line count: " + countLines(test2));
    }

    private static int countLines(String s) {
        try (
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(s);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(sr)
        ) {
            int count = 0;
            for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
                count++;
            }
            return count;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

}
```

I expected countLines to return **5** in both cases, but it returns **4** for the first string.

Background: I actually need the value of **line** to fill an array of strings and expected the last element to be the empty string.

**Edit:** I already know that

```
String[] lines = s.split("\n", -1);
int count = lines.length;
```

will give me the correct/expected number of lines. I only ask for performance reasons and if somebody can tell if BufferedReader behaves correctly.

Comment: Why do you expect 5?

Comment: I actually need the value of **line** to fill an array of strings and expected the last element to be the empty string (for further UI stuff).

Comment: I have updated the answer explaining the behavior of `BufferedReader#readline()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [code](http://ideone.com/BRz2mg).

```
class LineCountTest
{
    private static final String test = "This is a\ntest string\n\n\n";
    private static final String test2 = "This is a\ntest string\n\n\n ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Line count: " + countLines(test));
        System.out.println("Line count: " + countLines(test2));
    }

    private static int countLines(String s) {
        return (s + " ").split("\r?\n").length;
    }
}
```

This will solve your problem.

This code splits the string by `\r\n` or `\n` and return the number of lines.

The additional blank space is added so that the last line is counted even if it is empty.

The `BufferedReader` is behaving correctly.

The condition `line != null` is causing the problem.

In the string `test`, there is **nothing** after the last `\n`, which is read as `null` by `BufferedReader#readLine()` and thats why the loop terminates and the output is `4`.

In the string `test2`, there is a **blank space** after the last `\n`, which allows another iteration and the output is `5`.

Comment: I can agree with that, but then the BufferedReader approach really isn't a valid method to count the lines in a string? Every text editor displays/counts blank lines and numbers them correctly.

Comment: Not all the text-editors use `BufferedReader` approach to count the lines. Some editors on Windows OS like *Notepad* doesn't even recognize `\n` and displays entire text in a single line.

Also, some of the rich text editors use HTML for maintaining the content. `<br>` helps that way. HTML also help in highlighting keywords.

Comment: Final conclusion: `s.split("\n", -1);` is the method of coice to get the lines or count the number of lines in a string; the buffered reader approach differs in behavior though performance is better.

Answer (score 0):

So you found that a last line is recognized when it ends with a `\n` or is non-empty.

For your purposes one might be able to use:

```
String[] lines = "This is a\ntest string\n\n\n".split("\r?\n", 5);
```

This assures that the array will have 5 elements. Regex split is a bit slower though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I already know this. I just wanted to use the code above for better performance and was wondering if this behavior of BufferedReader is valid.

Comment: **An empty file should have 0 lines**, isn't it? Though a line normally ends with a newline, one also does **not want to loose text in a file not ending with a newline.** So I think this is the most logical choice.

Answer (score 0):

if you add an extra space in your first string.

```
private static final String test = "This is a\ntest string\n\n\n ";
```

you will get both same count.
The main reason is in  for loop :

```
for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) 
{
        count++;
}
```

third parameter of for loop "line = br.readLine()" only return a string if after "\n" is there available any other string . in your first string there have no other character but in your second string you add a space and this space now consider as a new string. that's why you get 4 and 5 count number.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8 then:

```
long lines = stringWithNewlines.chars().filter(x -> x == '\n').count() + 1;
```

(+1 in the end is to count last line if string is trimmed)